# How to pass default value for relation fields while inserting a record through doctrine in symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How to pass default value for relation fields while inserting a record through doctrine in symfony2?

My entity insert query is as follows

```
$this->hospitalAdminAppointment->setAppDetail($this->venReqAppReason)
    ->setvendor($vendor)
    ->setHospAdminApp($HospitalRequestedAppointment)
    ->setAppSuperAdmin($superAdmin)
    ->setPostedByHospSuperUser($postedByHospSuperUser)
    ->setAppPrimaryCompany($primaryCompany)
    ->setAppSecondaryCompany($secondryCompany)
    ->setAppDepartment($this->deptName)
    ->setAppDate(new \DateTime($this->appointmentDate))
    ->setAppTime(new \DateTime($this->appointmentTime))
    ->setAppPerson($person)
    ->setAppAdddedBy(AppointmentRequestAddedByType::VENDOR_REQUEST)
    ->setAppFromCalender('')
    ->setVendorRequestedAppointment($vendorRequestedAppointment)
    ->setAppHospital($hospital);

$this->em->persist($this->hospitalAdminAppointment);
$this->em->flush();
```

Here "AppSuperAdmin" field is in relation to another table and its type is integer and "not allow null" it's taking "0" through normal MySQL query.

We can't get AppSuperAdmin value for every time. Sometimes we need to pass it just zero.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are setting the value for variable $superAdmin. The easiest way is to check if $superAdmin is set, if yes set that value, otherwise set 0 like this:

```
->setAppSuperAdmin($superAdmin? $superAdmin : 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers but
setAppSuperAdmin is needed $object.
It does not allow me to give null or 0

Comment: post the code for your AppSuperAdmin class, I need to see the fields and the constructor.